# Does camel simple language support nested EL?

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Spring DSL in camel. I need substring of filename and camel throws error when using nested EL. Below is the code failed at 3rd log.

```
  <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
          <constant>sarada_chelluboyena_08032018.txt</constant>
    </setHeader>

    <log message="${header.CamelFileName.indexOf('chelluboye')}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
    <log message="${header.CamelFileName.substring(9,15)}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
    <log message="${header.CamelFileName.substring(${header.CamelFileName.indexOf('chelluboye')},15)}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
```

Comment: Try without ${} for inner expression ${header.CamelFileName.substring(header.CamelFileName.indexOf('chelluboye'),15)}

Comment: After removing ${} the value is always null

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: @ClausIbsen It's Camel v2.19

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using Groovy

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>  
  <artifactId>camel-groovy</artifactId>  
</dependency>  

<setHeader headerName="FileDate">  <groovy>request.headers.get("CamelFileName").substring((request.headers.get("CamelFileName").indexOf("TEST")+7),(request.headers.get("CamelFilName").indexOf("TEST")+13))</groovy>  
</setHeader>
```